# form.submit returning false still Page Redraws

Tags: javascript, form-submit

```
$('#GramForm').submit(function () {
    // Ajax Save New Style If Available.
    SaveNewStyle() // this function also return false.

    return false;
});
```

This is my code. But the problem is when form is submitted it redraw whole page.
What could be the possible reason for this problem?

Thanks for you help in advance. 
Regards.

Comment: Do you see anything in the browser's console?

Comment: I am betting there is a JavaScript error on your page. In order to see it, you need to set the console to "*Preserve log upon navigation*". This will keep the logs statements around instead of clearing them so you can see the errors thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use preventDefault to stop the form submission.

```
$('#GramForm').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();  //stop the form submission

    // Ajax Save New Style If Available.
    SaveNewStyle() // this function also return false.

    return false;
});
```

The reason why the return false is failing is you must have a JS error in the `SaveNewStyle` which is not allowing the return false to run. See my comment above on preserving the log so you can see the error.